# How to disable onTouch of some potion in view

Tags: android, view, touch-event

I'm drawing an rectangle surface by using canvas and i want to disable onTouchEvent() of some part of area, example if you tap(Touch) right side of the rectangle it should not perform onTouchEvent(). can any one tell me How to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `onTouchEvent`, check if the `MotionEvent` is within touchable area and return false if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Hit and Trial method and generate a formula to run your app on different screen size of devices. And check where the user clicked and if he clicked in the restricted region do nothing.

Like

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    if (x<height-100 && y>width-100) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}else{
//Do what you want here
}
```